# Drone tipping over when attempting to fly (possible accelerometer problem?)

Tags: gyro

This is my first time building a drone, so sorry if this is a stupid question or I use the wrong words. When I attempt to fly my drone, it immediately tips over (link to video here: https://youtu.be/og8w9KjhzBI). I know its not a problem with the motors themselves because when i turn the motors on using Betaflight Configurator, they all spin at the same speeds. I made sure my accelerometer was properly calibrated through Betaflight, and have searched the web for hours attempting to find an answer to no avail. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Some very common causes of this are a) props mounted incorrectly (as pion mentioned) and b) motors spinning the incorrect direction. Check that all the motors are spinning the right way. If any aren't, just swap two of the motor wires.

Answer (score 4):

Some simple things to look for before we go deeper:

1. Did you check that all four props are mounted correctly? (**CW** on top left + bottom right, **CCW** on top right + bottom left)
2. With your **props off(!)**, your drone connected to the Betaflight Configurator, and your control inputs neutral, are all three control axes all centered (at $1500$) in the Receiver pane?

Answer (score 3):

Assuming it's not as simple as incorrect prop rotation, it could be that you have a mismatch between the FC orientation and the motor positions. Try holding the quad while it's running (with the props off) and tipping it in each direction. The lowest motor should speed up and the highest one slow down.

Before you change anything, check whether the control inputs are right - if you move the stick right, the motors on the right should slow down.

Also, you can just check that the drone rotation in Betaflight matches reality when it's connected to the computer.